# Get data from input type radio using ajax

Tags: ajax

My problem with my code is that it returns the first value which is "male" and even if i click the female button it will still return the value "male". This is just my snippet..

**func.php**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input onchange="gen()" name="gender" type="radio" value="male" />Male
<input onchange="gen()" name="gender" type="radio" value="female" />Female
<script>
function gen(){
    $.ajax({
      type:"post",
      url:"ajax.php",
      data:{
         gender_val:$("[name=gender]").val(),
      },
      success:function(msg){
       alert(msg);
    }
    })
}
</script>
```

and my ajax.php goes like this

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
echo $_POST['gender_val'];
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by *same value* and *my real code was actually an array*?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What exactly do you need help with? You just posted some jQuery related to an ajax request? What does the PHP processing file do?

Comment: I edited my questions to make it more clear thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the selected value , you can use this instead.

```
gender_val:$("input[name=gender]:checked").val()
```